# Spring check if a lazy bean is instantiated

Tags: java, spring

Suppose I have a lazy Spring managed bean `MyBean` within a custom scope like this:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

    @Scope("custom")
    @Lazy
    @Bean
    MyBean myBean () {
        return new MyBean();
    }

}
```

and another Spring managed bean:

```
@Component
class MyBeanCounter{
    void checkIfMyBeanIsInstantiated () {
    // Check if there is an instance of MyBean within Spring context
    } 
}
```

Within `checkIfMyBeanIsInstantiated` I want to check if there is an instance of MyBean within Spring context without triggering the bean creation.

The obvious idea is to inject `MyBean` like this:

```
@Component
class MyBeanCounter {
    @Autowired
    MyBean myBean;

    void checkIfMyBeanIsInstantiated () {
        if (myBean != null) {// this doesn't trigger the bean creation
            // there is an instance
        }
    } 
}
```

<strike>The problem with the above solution is that I have to refresh the `MyBeanCounter` every time the `MyBean` instance changes according to it's custom scope.</strike>

The above solution doesn't work because `@Autowired MyBean myBean;` does instantiate the bean. Replacing it with `@Lazy @Autowired MyBean myBean;` still doesn't work since I end up with an injected proxy.

Is there any solution?

Comment: If you need to refresh it, then your scope is broken.

Comment: The scope should generate a proxy and the proxy should obtain the correct object, based on the scope. You shouldn't need to refresh anything in your services and other compoments. If you have build a scope that needs that, your scope is implemented wrong.

Comment: A prototype isn't a scoped bean. You **can** create a scoped prototype which as a result would then create a new instance of the bean for each method called on that bean, however this is all handled transparently for the using bean (the service). The same applies to the request, session, thread scoped beans. You will get a proxy which will then, based on the scope, delegate the proper instance of that bean.

Comment: As stated in my initial comment, you are trying to fix things you shouldn't be fixing and those come from a wrongly implemented scope.

Comment: @M.Deinum The "wrongly implemented scope" is `org.springframework.context.support.SimpleThreadScope`. I did not implement anything. By default, this scope does not provide any proxy. I found out that, in order to have a proxied scoped (which you call unbroken) I have to use `@Scope(value="scope_name",  proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)` or `ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES` for JDK proxy mechanism, on the target bean. The scope implementation has nothing to do with the proxy part.

Comment: Correct it hasn't .The scoping mechanism itself has (which is proxy based and you will always have an instance!) and if you want to use that you will have to specify the proxy mode else it simply won't work. And the `SimpleThreadScope` is also simple and has a big ceveat it will not cleanup properly (as mentioned in the documentation of said scope) when using this with threads in a thread pool. As a scoped instance is associated with the thread (through a threadlocal). However you nowhere mentioned that in your question (the thread scope) nor do you explain clearly what you want or try to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you seem to not actually need or want the instance in the check, just do

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

    @Scope("custom")
    @Lazy
    @Bean
    MyBean myBean (MyBeanCounter counter) {
        counter.setBeanInstantiated();
        return new MyBean();
    }

}

@Component
class MyBeanCounter {
    @Setter
    private boolean beanInstantiated;

    void checkIfMyBeanIsInstantiated () {
        if (beanInstantiated) {
            // there is an instance
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: It definitely works. The only issue I see: it unnaturally bounds the  `MyBean` creation to `MyBeanCounter`

Comment: @EugenCovaci not sure why you'd call that "unnatural". The requirement is to know if the bean was created, so creation is the correct time to bind. Also, it's not bound via the beans itself but via the configuration. If that still is to much, you can use aspects, but that would be overkill imo.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Component
class MyBeanCounter {
   @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext appContext;

    void checkIfMyBeanIsInstantiated () {
         String[] beans= appContext.getBeanDefinitionNames();
         // now loop the beans and if it is Null it has not been Instantiated 
         // beans will contain all the beans name   
      } 
}
```

Comment: `getBeanDefinitionNames` gives me all the the bean definitions, regardless of current instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

For the "refresh" issue, make sure your scope uses a proxy which will help you retrieve the correct bean instance. You can add `proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS` to your `@Scope` annotation. This way you won't need to reload the `MyBeanCounter` so that it uses the new instance.

As for checking if the bean has bean initialized, you can directly check if it's different to null. A non initialized bean is equals to null.

So your `checkIfMyBeanIsInstantiated` could be as follows:

```
void checkIfMyBeanIsInstantiated () {
    if(myBean == null) {
       // Not initialized
       return;
    }
    // Initialized
}
```

Also make sure you add `required = false` to your @Autowired annotation:

```
@Autowired(required = false)
MyBean myBean;
```

If required is not set to false (it's default value is true), `myBean` will be instantiated right away because Spring see it as a required component for `MyBeanCounter`. By setting it to false and with using `@Lazy`, Spring will only initialize it when it's called.
But make sure you always test it for null to avoid a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: "This way you won't need to reload the MyBeanCounter so that it uses the new instance." is correct, but `appContext.containsBean(MY_BEAN_NAME))` always return true because, from javadoc `Does this bean factory contain a bean definition?`

Comment: @EugenCovaci Correct ! I updated my answer with a new check

Comment: Still not good because the injected `myBean` is a proxy, always not null.

Comment: Check out this snippet: https://gist.github.com/geowarin/f4094e4e9ef13ee43ab2
It retrieve the object from the proxy so you can check it from there

Comment: Not working, `ProxyUtils.getProxyTarget(myBean)` returns not null.

Comment: BTW, you know how I can mark a line as deleted in my question?

Comment: Why don't you add Lazy to the Autowired bean itself ? so it would be Autowired Lazy MyBean .... Or also take a look at LazyInitTargetSourceCreator, I've never used it but you can check if it can help you

And for the deleted line, I think you could edit the question and put the line between a <strike></strike> tag.

Comment: Thanks for the delete line tip, it worked. Using `@Lazy` doesn't work either, same proxy gets injected.

Answer (score 0):

If your bean is a singleton you could check if the bean is instantiated as follows:

```
  @Autowired
  private ApplicationContext context;

  @Test
  void testLazyBean(){
    AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory = (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory) context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
    Assertions.assertFalse(beanFactory.containsSingleton("MY_BEAN"));
    Assertions.assertNotNull(context.getBean("MY_BEAN"));
    Assertions.assertTrue(beanFactory.containsSingleton("MY_BEAN"));
  }
```